# Where should I lock a model to prevent race conditions while validating it on a Django admin change page?

Tags: django, select, locking, race-condition

The simplified case:

`models.py`:

```
class Candidate(Model):
    first_name = CharField(max_length=64)
    last_name = CharField(max_length=64)

class Ward(Model):
    no = PositiveIntegerField(unique=True)
    address = CharField(max_length=1024)
    population = PositiveIntegerField()

class Votes(Model):
    candidate = ForeignKey(Candidate, on_delete=CASCADE)
    ward = ForeignKey(Ward, on_delete=CASCADE)
    amount = PositiveIntegerField()
```

In each `Ward` each `Candidate` may receive `Votes.amount` votes and the winner of the election is the `Candidate` who receives the most votes aggregated over `Wards`. These votes are editable in Django admin:

`admin.py`:

```
class VotesInline(StackedInline):
    model = Votes

@register(Ward)
class WardAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (VotesInline,)
```

Now validation issues kick in. Obviously the sum of the `Votes.amount` for all `Candidates` must not exceed a `Ward`'s total `Ward.population`. However, such validation will be meaningless unless the `Ward` remains locked for the duration of the validation of all related `Votes`! Else a race condition may kick in if user A modifies `Ward.population` while user B modifies `Votes.amount` related to this `Ward`.

I know that I should lock the `Ward` with `select_for_update`, but I do not know where exactly should I lock it so that the lock lasts for the validation of all related `Votes`. I was thinking about doing this in `get_queryset`, but ofc this would be a horrible idea, as this would lock it even while only browsing, and not necessarily modyfying.

PS1: No, assuming that such race condition is rare and therefore unworthy of consideration is out-of-the-question.
PS2: Yes, I only need to lock `Ward`, because `Votes` are not meant to be edited independently.
PS3: I prefer locking to maintaining versions.

EDIT: The exact kind of the race condition I need to prevent: John Doe has received 15 votes in a Ward that has a population of 40. Now user A lowers the population to 20 while user B raises J.Doe's result to 30 votes. This should lead to fail validation because of the breakage of the invariant that the sum of votes must be <= than the ward's population; however, if two Django threads / processes process these request simultaneously, then it may happen that A's requests gets processed and saved to the database after B's request has successfully validated but before B's request has saved; and as a result internal inconsistency in the database is introduced that J.Doe has received more votes than the number of people eligible to vote.

However, as of now, I don't really care about a race condition of this kind: User A tries to withdraw 5 votes from Doe's result while user B adds 3 votes; they both simultaneously load the view and first A sets the number of votes to 10, while B, unaware of A's change, sets the number of votes to 15+3=18, so A's change is lost.

As a result I do not want to call `select_for_update` each time the change view is being loaded; but only for the duration of the validation methods of all forms on that view when these forms are submitted.

Comment: Does this help? https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/27477

Comment: @The_Cthulhu_Kid Could you kinldy see my edited question?

Comment: I'll have a think.

Comment: I am now thinking that perhaps the solution is to exploit the fact that `get_queryset` receinves `request` in its arguments and to simply use `select_for_update` only if request.method is POST?

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking if I can find other options for solving your issue.
But still I don't have alternative. When I assume that you update vote in admin page and want to lock it, I would write like below.

```
from django.db import transaction

class ExampleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        with transaction.atomic():
            vote = (obj.__class__.objects.select_for_update()get(id=obj.id))
            # select_for_update() also locks ward because of FK relationship
            if vote.amount > vote.ward.population:
                vote.amount = obj.amount
                vote.save()
            else:
                pass 
                # if amount is not beigger than population,
                # you just pass it without saving.

        super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)

admin.site.register(Votes, ExampleAdmin)
```

Comment: First, how does this prevent the race condition I was describing? Then, your usage of ModelAdmin.save_models seems to contradict Django documentation, which says: Warning: When overriding ModelAdmin.save_model() and ModelAdmin.delete_model(), your
code must save/delete the object. They aren’t meant for veto purposes, rather they allow you to perform extra
operations. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-methods

Comment: I read the django manual. I think you need to lock your model when you save it, anway. I can't find better place to check validation for your vote amounts before saving. I am also curious and looking forward to seeing other better(probably proper) options and ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Having read a bit of admin's source code (in particular `changeform_view` and `_changeform_view` from `django/contrib/admin`) as well as a bit of docu I think this *might* be the correct solution:

```
class VotesFormSet(BaseInlineFormSet):
    def clean(self):
        if any(self.errors);
            return
        if sum([
            (form.cleaned_data['amount'] if 'amount' in form.cleaned_data else 0)
            for form in self.forms
        ]) > self.instance.population:
            raise ValidationError('More votes than people eligible to vote.')

class VotesInline(StackedInline):
    model = Votes
    formset = VotesFormSet

@register(Ward)
class WardAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (VotesInline,)

    def get_queryset(self, request);
        if request.method == "POST":
            # changeform_view already wraps both get_queryset
            # and the clean methods in atomic so I think it's not needed here
            return qs.select_for_update()
        else:
            return qs
```

But I won't swear blind it's the correct solution. I suppose it is, but I'm not 100% sure.